# SQL select where group by order by distinct

Tags: sql-server

I got a one table Search, and columns are:

```
id(int), title(nvarchar), count(int), expression(nvarchar)
```

with values:

```
1, aaa, 5, car 
2, aaa, 5, car poster
3, bbb, 8, car magazine
4, bbb, 8, car tv
5, ccc, 12, boat
6, ccc, 12 , boat tv
```

I need the following result

```
4, bbb, 8, car tv
3, bbb, 8, car magazine
2, aaa, 5, car poster
1, aaa, 5, car
```

or better result whatever from `4,3` and `2,1`
like this:

```
3, bbb, 8, car magazine
2, aaa, 5, car poster
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT   title 
FROM 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM Search 
     ORDER BY count DESC) 
WHERE expression 
LIKE '%car%'
GROUP BY  title
```

I have also tried a `DISTINCT`

Comment: In your "better Result" why did car tv go away?  because it had the higher ID for a given title and you want to show the lower ID?

Comment: nope ... I want just one title bbb and one aaa ... doesnt matter which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) with the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) function to find the matching rows and order them by descending count along with id for a tie breaker. Then select the first numbered row within each partition (title).

```
WITH cteFindCar AS (
    SELECT id, title, count, expression,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY title ORDER BY count DESC, id) AS RowNum
        FROM search
        WHERE expression LIKE '%car%'
)
SELECT id, title, count, expression
    FROM cteFindCar
    WHERE RowNum = 1;
```